# Flutter assign generic Future<T> from function callback

Tags: flutter

Why does not generic  `Future<T>` assign work? i Get this error: `A value of type 'Future<T>?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Future<T>?'.`

```
typedef SimpleFutureFunction<T> = Widget Function(void Function(Future<T>? newFuture) onFuture);

class SimpleFuture<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  const SimpleFuture({Key? key, required this.simple, this.future}) : super(key: key);

  final SimpleFutureFunction simple;
  final Future<T>? future;

  @override
  State<SimpleFuture> createState() => _SimpleFutureState();
}

class _SimpleFutureState<T> extends State<SimpleFuture<T>> {
  Future<T>? _future;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _future = widget.future;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.simple.call(<T>(Future<T>? newFuture) {
      setState(() {
        _future = newFuture;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: `_SimpleFutureState();` is not passing the type T parameter to the constructor of your state.  Maybe add <T> there?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz still same error